AWS Cognito : Unable to get user session following successful sign-in
I'm using AWS Cognito to authenticate my application.
I created a user pool, an app client and added a custom domain.
It works well on local.
Now I need to deploy on a remote server : it works too when I use the IP address, but not when I use the https domain.
Use of IP address:

http://"IP address":"port" -> give me Cognito login page -> login OK -> I'm redirected to my application home page
that's perfect !

Use of https domain:
But when I try to use my https domain, I get the error "Unable to get user session following successful sign-in."

https://"mydomain.org" -> give me Cognito login page -> login OK, but I stay on the login page and get the previous error

Chrome console:
Regarding the Chrome console network, the first calls to "https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/" seem OK, I see :

AuthFlow: "USER_SRP_AUTH"
ChallengeName: "PASSWORD_VERIFIER", I can see the tokens (IdToken, AccessToken...)

But I never go to the next calls "https://cognito-identity.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/"
which I have when I'm using the IP address.
I precise that I'm using a remote instance in Singapore, but my certificates were well imported in us-east-1.
I also use nginx on my remote server with a very simple configuration :
server {
        listen <port>;

        root /var/www/XXXX/html;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.XXXX.log warn;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.XXXX.log combined;
}

server {
    listen                      443 ssl;
    server_name                 my_domain;


    ssl_certificate             /etc/ssl/private/XXX.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/ssl/private/XXX.key;

    root /var/www/XXXX/html;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.XXXX.log warn;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.XXXX.log combined;
}

Any help please, it's been 2 days I'm trying to solve this :(.

I found a solution with this simple nginx configuration :
server {
    listen                      443 ssl;
    server_name                 my_domain;


    root /var/www/XXXX/html;

    ssl_certificate             <file_path>.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         <file_path>.key;

   location /api/ {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }

   location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
   }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.XXXX.log info;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.XXXX.log combined;
}

And also by checking the domain value in my Amplify configuration
loginWith: {
      oauth: {
        domain: XXXX,
        ...
     }
}

